# Analysis: How real functions are related to equation $\ x^3 - y^3 + x - y =0 $ in R3

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

The question is as follows:

> (1) What's the problem of solving for y in the equation $\ x^3 - y^3 + x
>  - y =0 $ ?
>
> (2) How many real functions, letting $\mathbb -infinity < x < \mathbb infinity $, s.t. the equation is defined?

I'm just confused >_<

For (1), the only thing that I can come up so far is that the equation is always true once y = x.  If I let z = $\ x^ 3 - y^3 + x - y$ , I suspect that I will get a plane. But then when z = 0 ?? I think I'll get a rectangle in x-y plane if I shrink the 3-D curve down to the 2-D.

For (2), I totally have no idea on what the question is asking.  But I think if indeed what I thought in (1) is true, then all real functions should work?

Please help me on this question.  I'm a bit lost.
Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: $x^3-y^3=?$ factorise it.

Comment: @exploringnet $\ x^3 - y^3 = (x - y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)$  But how is this helpful ? I tried this on the equation once and get y = x as the result >?<

Comment: Yes you got a plane $x-y+o*z=0$ No matter what is $z$.And after you shrink $R^3$ to $R^2$ then you get a line $x=y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what the question is asking for (2), either. Sorry!

I can help you out for (1), though. As you've noted in the comments above, $$x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2).$$ From this it follows that $$x^3-y^3+x-y=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2+1),$$ so $$x^3-y^3+x-y=0$$ if and only if $x=y$ or $x^2+xy+y^2+1=0$. Completing the square, we see that $$\begin{align}x^2+xy+y^2+1 &= x^2+2x\cdot\frac{y}2+y^2+1\\ &= x^2+2x\cdot\frac{y}2+\left(\frac{y}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{y}2\right)^2+y^2+1\\ &= \left(x+\frac{y}2\right)^2+\frac34y^2+1\\ &\ge 1\end{align}$$ for all real $x,y.$ Hence, $$x^3-y^3+x-y=0$$ if and only if $x=y.$